# Can't access Text of ColumnHeader (Template)

Tags: .net, wpf, datagrid, wpfdatagrid

WIthin the DataGridColumnHeader's template I have created a label that should only show a numeric value next to the header's text, if the multibinding matches the rules.

I have successfully created this code on a UserControl and its working as expected.

But now on a Windows Control, this doesn't work any longer and I am completely speechless why that is.

The line `<Binding Path="Text" Mode="TwoWay" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged"/>` within Multibinding is meant to bind to the Text property of the actual header.  But this binding doesn't seem to work.

I get the following error message:

> System.Windows.Data Warning: 40 : BindingExpression path error: 'Text'
>   property not found on 'object' ''iReportViewModel'
>   (HashCode=36680867)'. BindingExpression:Path=Text;
>   DataItem='iReportViewModel' (HashCode=36680867); target element is
>   'Label' (Name='ColumnHeaderSortingNumber'); target property is
>   'Content' (type 'Object')

But how comes this works on my other usercontrol with teh exact copy & pasted code?
Why is it looking at the ViewModel? I was expecting to access the ViewModel if its defined like this: Path="DataContext.Text" like the second row. This should have accessed the Text (title) within the same header.

Any idea to help me out would be highly appreciated,

```
<Style x:Key="DatagridColumnHeaderCustomTemplateStyle" TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}">
                 ...
                <Setter Property="Template">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}">
                            <Grid>
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    ...
                                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <theme:DataGridHeaderBorder>
                                   ...
                                </theme:DataGridHeaderBorder>
                                <Label FontSize="8" FontWeight="Bold" Background="Transparent" Style="{StaticResource ColumnHeaderSortingLabel}" x:Name="ColumnHeaderSortingNumber" Panel.ZIndex="1000" Visibility="Collapsed" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Margin="0" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" >
                                    <Label.Content>
                                        <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource ColumnHeaderDictionaryConv}" ConverterParameter="LookupSecond" Mode="TwoWay" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged">
                                            <Binding Path="Text" Mode="TwoWay" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged"/>
                                            <Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type DataGridCellsPanel}}" Path="DataContext.SortCollectionHeader" Mode="TwoWay" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged"/>
                                            <Binding ... />
                                        </MultiBinding>
                                    </Label.Content>
                                </Label>
                            </Grid>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Style>
```

Comment: I dont understand one thing. What is this `Text` property? Where does this belong to? `DataContext` of `DatagridColumnHeader` is always what value `DatagridColumnHeader.Header` is set to. You can check if that value is some object which has `Text` property.

Comment: @AngelWPF OK, how would I push in the title of the current Header into my MultiBinding? I need to know within my converter which column has been clicked on, hence I need the title. How would you do bind the first <Binding/> to the title of the column (header) please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably should know this already, if no source is specified in a `Binding` it will be looking for the property specified in `Path` in the `DataContext`. Sources are: `ElementName`, `Source` & `RelativeSource`, this is why you need `DataContext.X` in the second binding as that would be looking for the property on the source otherwise.

If you want to bind to a property on the control that owns the property you are bindng add `RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Self}"`. If you want to bind to a property on the templated parent you can either use a `TemplateBinding` or also use `RelativeSource` with `TemplatedParent` instead of `Self`.

Comment: Thanks HB, I agree with you.  But how would I bind with RelativeSource to the title of the header? I think I have to bind to the ContentPresenter somehow...But stuck on this.... Thanks

Comment: @Kave: Try to bind to `Column.Header` of the `TemplatedParent` (which should be [`DataGridColumnHeader`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.datagridcolumnheader.aspx)), if anywhere it should be stored there i think. However there might be problems with getting updates as the properties on the path do not appear to be dependency properties. You could also try the path `Content` on the `TemplatedParent`.

Comment: Fantastic. I got it working like this: <Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource TemplatedParent}" Path="Column.Header" Mode="TwoWay" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged"/> You are right about the RaisingPropertyChanged issue. But I already solve this with an additional Binding on a plain boolean MVVm property. Whenever that one is hit, the whole binding is re-calculated.  I can't thank you enough, this issue was becoming very time consuming for me.

Comment: @Kave: I've just been testing my suggestions, `Content` should work and provide notifications. Glad that helped :)

Comment: I can confirm <Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource TemplatedParent}" Path="Content" /> does also work. :) Thanks